# What are the drawbacks of using Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

In the tutorials I see only the benefits of Shadow DOM, but there should be drawbacks as well. In which cases should we avoid using Shadow DOM?

Comment: well, if your target browser is chrome, I don't see real drawbacks. Chrome is motivated to support it fully because of Polymer :)

Comment: the benefits can become drawbacks depending your viewpoint

Comment: @Supersharp okay, in which cases should I avoid using Shadow DOM (except compatibility issues)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shadow DOM features can be seen as drawback as much as benefits:

**Style isolation** is a benefit if you want it but a drawback if a user wants to style a component with Shadow DOM from a global CSS stylesheet.

**DOM Shadowing** is a benefit in some cases, but a drawback if an external script/library or extension needs to parse or select the content.

There are many 3rd party libraries (or extensions) that won't work with Shadow DOM content because they were not designed to deal with it, or need some additional configuration to work with Shadow DOM.

Examples:

- [Disqus comments integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770656/4600982)
- [CodeMirror editor integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42757381/4600982)
- [Wiris math editor integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45695409/4600982)

Also, extensions that parse HTML will be blocked at the Shadow DOM boundary: a benefit if you don't want to spied, a drawback if you consider them as a useful service.

**Event propagation** is different inside and outside the Shadow DOM. So you may have some difficulties dealing with UI events.

Example :

- [TinyMCE integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39939211/4600982)

**Conclusion**

- Use Shadow DOM only if you want CSS style or DOM isolation.
- Don't use Shadow DOM if you need to interact with some not compliant third party components or library.

Comment: There are other ways of isolating CSS (e.g. css modules) that don't cause as much side effects as the Shadow DOM. This can't be the only benefit to the Shadow DOM?

Answer (score 2):

Uh, ah, this technology's specification has not stabilized and is not supported by many browsers. I would call that a drawback.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow

For now I would say; Avoid in most cases, except when you want to experiment with new stuff and it is not for the production environment.

**UPDATE:** By now [all modern browsers support this feature](https://caniuse.com/?search=attachShadow).

Comment: They do have polyfills though

Comment: So it's perfect in every way, but too new?